# When using seaborn to draw heatmap, can I mark multiple rows as one label?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I am drawing a heatmap. I want to replace the original y-axis by its category. For example:
data:

```
                    Location 1    Location 2      Location 3
cluster 1:    0       0.3           0.5              0.7
cluster 1:    1       1.2           3.1              1.2
cluster 1:    2       0.8           0.1              1.3
cluster 2:    3       0.2           0.3              1.0
cluster 2:    4       3.1           2.1              5
cluster 3:    5       0.9           0.7              0.2
```

Instead of showing the index `(0,1,2,3,4,5)`, I want to show the cluster number for multiple rows.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the labels and position them at the average value. The minor y ticks can serve as separations.

The following code supposes the first column has the cluster labels (and won't be used for the heatmap itself).

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator

data_str = '''    cluster                "Location 1"    "Location 2"      "Location 3"
"cluster 1"         0.3           0.5              0.7
"cluster 1"         1.2           3.1              1.2
"cluster 1"         0.8           0.1              1.3
"cluster 2"         0.2           0.3              1.0
"cluster 2"         3.1           2.1              5
"cluster 3"         0.9           0.7              0.2'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
ax = sns.heatmap(df[df.columns[1:]], cmap='rocket_r', annot=True)

ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ticks = []
labels = []
prev_label = None
for i, label in enumerate(df['cluster']):
    if label != prev_label:
        ticks.append(i)
        labels.append(label)
        prev_label = label
ticks.append(i + 1)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(FixedLocator(ticks))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator([(t0 + t1) / 2 for t0, t1 in zip(ticks[:-1], ticks[1:])]))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels, rotation=0)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', length=0)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', length=60)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]